# magento web service

Tags: magento

i want to get product list by tax class id . how will i do it?

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $result = array();
    foreach ($collection as $product) { 
        $result[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'name'       => $product->getName(),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
            'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds()

             );

    }
```

this is my code how wil i modify it to get the result

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute filter on the product collection.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('tax_class_id', $my_tax_class_id);
```

Edit: sorry, I forgot to add the getCollection method to obtain the product collection instead of the model.

Comment: I tried it also and it is working fine. Are you sure you use the right tax id? Or do you get an error?

Comment: i used it bt just showing the whole product list nt filtering with the tax class id

Comment: maybe all products have the same tax_class_id? It should work this way.

Comment: class MyModule_Product_Model_Product_Api extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api
{public function taxableproduct()
{$my_tax_class_id=2;
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('tax_class_id', $my_tax_class_id);$result = array();foreach ($collection as $product){$result[] = array(         'product_id' => $product->getId(),'sku' => $product->getSku(),'name'=> $product->getName(),'set'=> $product->getAttributeSetId(),'type'=>$product->getTypeId(),'category_ids'=> $product->getCategoryIds() );
   
        }
        return $result;
 }
}

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is then, sorry. Your code seems correct. Maybe someone else knows.